Generate and download PDF with remix
I am getting the HTML from a component and sending it to an endpoint that will generate the PDF. After that I want to download that generated PDF.
This is the code I use to call the endpoint with and sending the html in the body:
const formDataHtml = formData.get('html') as string;
const html = new URLSearchParams({ html: formDataHtml });
    
const response = await fetchApi(`/pdf/html2pdf`, {
    request,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: html,
    shouldParseResponse: false,
    shouldStringifyBody: false,
});
    
if (!response.success) {
    return json({ error: response.error.message }, response.error.statusCode);
}
    
const pdfFileData = response.data as PdfFileData;
const pdfBuffer = await new Response(pdfFileData.body).arrayBuffer();
const pdfUint8Array = new Uint8Array(pdfBuffer);
    
return new Response(pdfUint8Array, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=protokol.pdf`,
    },
}); 

And this is the Download PDF button that triggers the download:
function DownloadPDFForm({endpoint, html, children}) {
    const fetcher = useFetcher<any>();
    const downloadRef = React.useRef<HTMLAnchorElement>(null);
    const args = { html };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const response = fetcher.data;
        if (!response) return;

        const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'file.pdf';
        a.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, [fetcher.data]);

    function onClick() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.set('endpoint', endpoint);
        formData.set('intent', 'download-pdf');
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(args)) formData.append(key, value);

        fetcher.submit(formData, {
            action: '/api/manage-files',
            method: 'POST',
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className={cn('flex items-center')}>
            <a className="sr-only" ref={downloadRef} href={fetcher.data?.url}>
                DOWNLOAD
            </a>
            <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>DOWNLOAD PDF</button>
        </div>
    );
} 


When calling the endpoint, it triggers the PDF download, but all pages are blank. The bigger the formDataHtml is, the more pages I get in the downloaded PDF, although all pages are blank.
NOTE: The formDataHtml, html are not null, since I console.log-ed them (also tested with some basic HTML)

I had to dig a bit to find what was the issue, and apparently is a Remix server related thing. My workaround was to decode the base64 string that comes back from the server:
const base64ToBuffer = (base64: string): ArrayBuffer => {
const binaryString = window.atob(base64); // Decode base64 string
const length = binaryString.length;
const bytes = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(length));

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
}

return bytes.buffer;
};

